# Bootstrap tables taking long loading time on large amount of record

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, performance

I'm using Bootstrap tables to show records in table format coming from Mysql Database.

As Records are more than 6000, It takes a long time to load all the data. It makes my application very slow. Can we load data when we click on page numbers? So initially it supposed to take only 20 records than one-page number click it supposed to take next 20 records. Something like that?

Comment: Use pagination I think

Comment: use pagination... refer http://www.a2zwebhelp.com/php-mysql-pagination

Comment: Use jquery datatable plugin, its a life saver in such situations. Ex: https://pandeyz.github.io/Jquery-datatable-client-side-demo-implementation/.  It comes up with pagination, sorting and many more facilities

Comment: Why not use pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Client side pagination will have the same impact since the data is loaded during the page load. If initial loading time is your concern, then server side pagination `data-side-pagination="server"` is what you want, because (obviously) it reduces the effort of the server as it divides the requests by chunks depending on the page limit. It's documented in their site [here](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#options/server-side-pagination.html)

```
<table id="table"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-url="/examples/bootstrap_table/data"
           data-height="400"
           data-side-pagination="server"
           data-pagination="true"
           data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
           data-search="true">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="id">ID</th>
            <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
        </thead></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you have a lot of records, it is better to show only chunks of it at a time. This will greatly reduce the amount of time it takes for a page to load.

You can select chunks by using [`LIMIT {start}, {amount}`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#idm139962744969456) in your MySql queries.

Comment: But how can we integrate it with jquery or bootstrap tables?

Comment: You can show a pager under your table and let those links navigate to the same page ending in `?page=3` for example. On the server side, you can load the elements for that page according to the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Use pagination
2. Load data using Ajax (load by part of 100 records)

Answer (score 0):

Pagination via `OFFSET` has performance problems.  Instead, "remember where you left off".  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination for discussion of the technique.